# Does recycle call Application_Start?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

Does Application_Start get called on recycling in IIS 7?

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it gets called on the first request after recycling when the application is actually loaded by IIS.

Comment: but not after the second recycling?

Comment: `Application_Start` gets called everytime IIS loads the application. First, second, third, ... nth. But not when it is recycled but when the application starts which as I already pointed out in my answer could happen when the first request hits the application after being recycled.

Comment: So it does get called in result to its recycling?
Does Recycling start a new process?

Comment: Lior, no recycling simply brings down the AppDomain that is hosting your application. Nothing else happens until the next request comes in. Unless, there's one unless => you have configured AutoStart feature (available only in IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008) for this application pool in which case immediately after recycling IIS will start the pool.

Comment: Recycling does start a new process. By default, the old and new processes may overlap for a period of time too.

Comment: @rally25rs, yes, you are correct indeed. The process could be renewed but the ASP.NET application won't start until a request is sent or AutoStart feature is activated. And it is the starting of the ASP.NET application that triggers the Application_Start method.

Comment: Ok thank you.
So that means that if I created new threads on application start, recycling doesn't call for a new creation of them but it does kill them. Right?

Comment: @Lior, yes absolutely. And this is true not only for threads you have created in `Application_Start`. It is true for all threads. This is one of the reasons why you should avoid doing such things in an ASP.NET application as Phil Haack explains: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx