# IIS idle timeout and Application_Start

Tags: iis, application-start

I have an MVC web app hosted in IIS.The Idle timeout in the application pool configuration option has the default value of 20 minutes.That means that the  application pool will terminate after 20 minutes so that it can start up again on the next visit.On this next visit Application_Start declared in Global.asax will be executed again?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, Application_Start will be executed. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027471/does-recycle-call-application-start

Comment: Ok,thank you very much