# How to simulate IIS App-Pool shutdown due to timeout

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

I am facing an error in production due to IIS application pool shutdown during App-pool time out.

I want to reproduce the scenario in my local machine, however even if set low application pool time-out (5 minutes or 1 minute), it doesn't shutdown.

If I shutdown the application pool in the IIS user interface, it doesn't serve new requests. I want to simulate the scenario how it is shutdown and awake automatically when a new request comes in.

Thanks in advance,
Pandiarajan.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of issuing a Stop command, use "Recycle". This will create a new instance of the AppPool and shutdown the old one.

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio for the comments, App-Pool recycle and App-Pool shutdown are different. With recycle the App-Pool all the objects are loaded in the memory immediately. But in case of app-pool shutdown, objects are loaded only when a new request comes in. Recycle didn't help me.

Comment: @Pandiarajan please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027471/does-recycle-call-application-start  A recycle does not immediately starts the application. It waits for a new request coming in.

Comment: You may be right. But when I look by **appcmd list apppool ** the application pool is still present and shows as started. Where as in production **appcmd list apppool ** doesn't display the application pool which was recycled.